# If cold air is denser then why is compression associated with atmospheric heating?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atmospheric-science, density, meteorology

If cold air is denser than warm air then I would assume compression of air would cause air to cool and expansion would cause air to heat up. Why is it the opposite?

Comment: Hmmm. I was gonna answer this, but then I realized a complete and correct answer, even if it was as concise as possible would be quite long, and I got lazy... Anyways, I think this belongs to physics stack exchange, as there is nothing aviation specific here. Good question though.

Comment: @Jpe61 Isn't it just PV/T = PV/T, right? Density being inversely related to volume, since PV = nRT as well. Agree that this is Physics, not Aviation. The ***act*** of compression raises Temperature, but when P1 = P2, lower Volume means lower Temperature (and lower V = greater density).

Comment: Saying "if you chill something, it gets dense" is simply not the same as saying "if you compress something, it gets cold".  Can you think of a single example where anyone has ever cooled something by compressing it?  I'm not sure I see enough substance here to be worthy of an actual question.  It's like saying "if I push the accelerator pedal down, my car goes faster, so why doesn't the accelerator pedal move downward when I pick up speed by rolling down a steep hill?

Comment: Compressing air (or any other gas) makes it warmer TEMPORARILY.  Then it cools down to ambient temperature.  Heating it while maintaining the same volume increases the pressure - that's why you're supposed to check tire pressure when the tires are cold, not after driving has warmed them up.  See also chinook winds.

Comment: The Chinook phenomenon in Alberta is a great example of major atmospheric compression heating and the bootstrap effect. Air rises over the BC coastal mountains and cools at the wet adiabatic lapse rate if 3F/1000 ft, loses most of its moisture from the climb, crosses the interior plateau where it picks up a bit of extra heat, then comes cascading down the east side of the Rockies,  rapidly compression heating at the dry adiabatic lapse rate of  5.4 F/1000 ft.  And Calgary basks in 60 F weather for a few days in between bouts of -0F.

Comment: @RalphJ yes that's the formula, but to explain the formula would have taken too much tapping, to cover enough on the subject there's for example adiabatics and stuff 

Comment: @RalphJ when P1=P2 lower*ing* temperature means lower volume.  This is really the crux of the question.  Rais*ing* pressure by reduc*ing* volume means higher temperature.  To finish the Chinook story (and Santa Ana),  dry air is heavier than moist air (at the same T and P, because H2O (18) is lighter than N2 (28) and O2 (32)), and it will sink and compress, further raising its temperature.  Winds in the Western mountains must be seen to be believed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_laws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing compresses air to make it colder.  Temperature is based on movement of molecules.  As air radiates heat, the molecules move slower and slower, reaching liquid state if cooling continues, and eventually frozen solid. (thank goodness for the sun).  Slower moving molecules generally have greater density because they do not push each other apart as much.

From this data we can deduce that "temperature" or warmth is based on *emission* of heat, caused by number of molecular collisions *and* the kinetic energy of each collision. (Now *that* is starting to sound like something to do with aviation, no?)

This in turn is based on the energy *input* into the system.

Compression (within a cylinder) increases the number of collisions, which increases temperature.  But compressed air will cool, and if released to ambient pressure, will be cooler.

Temperature of air at the same pressure can be raised by input of solar radiation, causing the molecules to move faster.  This *raises* pressure within a closed system, *but lowers density in an open system*.

In an open system (such as a hot air balloon) **pressure remains the same, density changes based on temperature**.  In a closed system **pressure changes with temperature**.  Density cannot change unless the volume is changed by physical compression or expansion.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that if you add energy by compressing the air then it must become warmer.  Looking at it another way, pressure is created by air molecules bouncing off the container (or surroundings) and so if you put the same air into a smaller container the molecules will collide with the container more frequently.  Cold air is denser because the collisions that would push the molecules apart are less frequent.

Comment: @Frog not less frequent, less energetic.  Compression increases the number of collisions, but the temperature increase is only temporary.  If compressed gas is allowed to cool to ambient temperature, releasing it to ambient pressure creates a cooling effect.  This is how air conditioners work.

Answer (score 3):

This all depends upon the context. In a constant volume and pressure environment, a unit volume of cold air will be denser than a unit volume of warmer air.  In an adiabatic compression, the work done to compress a unit mass to air into a smaller volume will be stored in the gas as internal energy ie heat.  Given that air can be modeled very accurately as an ideal gas, this relationship may be expressed as P = pRT. This is why air heats up when compressed by work applied to a closed system.

Answer (score 2):

In order to fully describe the air for the purposes of this question, we need three properties: the temperature $T$, the density $\rho$, and, the one you didn't explicitly mention in your question, the pressure $P$.  These three properties are related in the following way: $$P\propto \rho T.$$
This relationship explains your first observation: that cold air is denser.  For any given value of $P$ (ambient atmospheric pressure, say), if $T$ decreases then $\rho$ must increase and vice versa.

What happens in second situation--compression of the air--is that all three variables, $P$, $\rho$, and $T$, change at the same time.  You can't determine from the relationship $P\propto \rho T$ alone what happens, because you're no longer holding any one of them constant. You need another relationship.  When you do the compression without adding or removing any heat it so happens that: $$P\propto \rho^{7/5}.$$

This says that when you squish the gas, increasing its density, you increase the pressure even more (the exponent determines how much more; $7/5$ is the amount for diatomic gasses like $\text{O}_2$ and $\text{N}_2$). Looking back at the first equation, that means that you also increase the temperature.

These two expression tell you $what$ happens, but not $why$. The reason can be understood in terms of energy. The total internal energy of a collection of gas molecules depends only on its temperature. When you compress a gas, you are doing work on it: adding energy to it.  If no energy is removed by other means, the internal energy must increase. So compressing a gas increases its temperature.

Comment: The 7/5 exponent is only valid for two-atomic gasses; it might be worth to point this out. And when you are at it: Use $\rho$ for density.